# How to style android native apps

Tags: android, css, android-layout, native

I am somewhat new to android development and the apps I make with it are I would say ugly. I don't like the usual style provided . So I wish to know if there is anyway to style it . Maybe something that allows to style components like using CSS . Anyway applying your own style like border, colour, gradient color, RGB etc

Answer (score 0):

There is very good and detailed tutorial [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)

and check also [this](https://material.io/develop/android/) site.

The general solution is to use themes and colors and adjust everything.
Material design can be useful for you.

For video about styling take a look at [Youtube video style modern ui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOcD1evBcSA&t=366s)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out android UI dev tutorials on youtube. There are some good resources on there. Good luck on your journey into android mobile application development.